# Why does this code only read the first line rather than the whole .txt file?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a code here on Python 2.7 that is supposed to tell me the frequency of a letter or word within a single text file.

```
def frequency_a_in_text(textfile, a):
    """Counts how many "a" letters are in the text file.
    """

    try:
        f = open(textfile,'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()

    except IOError:
        return -1

    tot = 0
    for line in lines:
        split = str(line.split())
        k = split.count(s)
        tot = tot + k
        return tot

print frequency_a_in_text("RandomTextFile.txt", "a")
```

There's a little bit of extra coding in there - the "try" and "except", but that's just telling me that if I can't open the text file, then it'll return a "-1" to me.

Whenever I run it, it seems to just read the first line and tell me how many "a" letters there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning out of the function after the first iteration of your loop.

The return statement should be outside of the loop.

```
for line in lines:
    split = str(line.split())
    k = split.count(s)
    tot = tot + k
return tot
```

Comment: Ahh, a noob mistake. Thank you very much! I'll accept your answer in two minutes. There's a time limit which is stopping me. Edit: Accepted now. Thank again!